# How to customize slider in xamarin form?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to customize a slider so that it looks like the picture below:

[image: Target slider image]

My code in file .xaml :

```xml
<Slider MaximumTrackColor="Black" 
        MinimumTrackColor="Black" 
        HeightRequest="50" 
        ThumbColor="Black"
        ThumbImageSource="iconsc.png"
></Slider>
```

Result :

[image]

Can anyone help me to customize the slider so that it looks like the picture at the top?

Comment: Update your ThumbImageSource with correct image(green circle with black border).
For  dark & think line you will have to create custom slider then

Comment: Hi @bhavyajoshi, can you show me some document about Custom slider?

Comment: Go through this link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/customize-slider-control-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to achieve what you want in Xamarin.Forms 4.5.x by the following XAML code :

```
        <Slider
            Maximum="5"
            MaximumTrackColor="Yellow"
            Minimum="0"
            MinimumTrackColor="Black"
            ThumbColor="Yellow"
            Value="3">
            <Slider.ThumbImageSource>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="{StaticResource Star}"
                    Size="64"
                    Color="{DynamicResource SystemYellow}" />
            </Slider.ThumbImageSource>
        </Slider>
```

[image]

Using fonts is easy, please read this great article in order to use them :
https://montemagno.com/using-font-icons-in-xamarin-forms-goodbye-images-hello-fonts/